# How to write simple adaptive video stream server?

Tags: video, video-streaming, streaming, mpeg-dash

I need to write a very simple adaptive video stream server. But I don't know where to start. I couldn't find a decent tutorial for this. Simply what I need is changing the video quality when my internet speed drops.

So basically I will have different versions of my video in my server directory, and switch between them based on user connection. I just want to see it changing and how it works, that's it. What would you suggest for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are open source web and android players you can look and and go through their ABR algorithms to give you some idea, or to even reuse if their and your licensing allows.

This article will give you a good starting point and refers to DASH.JS player: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tldr-abr-algorithms-mpeg-dash-vijaya-sagar-vinnakota/

You can see a demo here with sample code to add rules: https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/abr/abr.html